# How to determine Ram/Rom usage of elf using binutils?

Tags: object, elf, binutils, nm, readelf

I would like to extract the Ram and Rom usage of each module by the help of binutils tools. I have a couple of objects (relocatable elf files) and a final executable (elf) to determine those data from.

I am writing a reusable (among different compilers) backend for memory analysis. Compilers tend to create a map file and store the informationen i am looking for, so i could write a tool to convert those map files in uniform format, but i would rather use the elf files which are already uniform and write a routine that extract those data for once.

I haven't acutally implemented something yet, since i am not quite sure which route to take.

I would love to hear about related project or some tipps or information about the topic in general. I have done my research, but could only find the suggestions to use "elfread", "nm" or "size" from binutils, which is what i am already doing.

Comment: Based on your question, it's unclear why you can't get the data you need directly from the ELF files or from `nm` or `size`.

Comment: size did the job, thanks a lot :)